# I am trying to run sudo in python to open an application

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt4, sudo

For example, if I wanted to call synaptic on my python script, this is what I tried but I'm getting error with Popen. Is there anyway to make this work with sudo instead of gksu? I would like to use this method to run scripts within a larger program.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("sudo synaptic", 'w', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1).write(password)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'bufsize'
```

Below is what I am working with

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import sys
import subprocess
# from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class PasswordDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PasswordDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        PasswordDialog.resize(self, 375, 130)
        PasswordDialog.setWindowTitle(self, "Enter Password")
        self.buttonOk = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonOk.setText("OK")
        self.buttonCancel = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonCancel.setText("Cancel")
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setFocus()

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setText("Enter your password to perform administrative Tasks")
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setText("Password")
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.horizontalLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonCancel)
        self.horizontalLayout2.addWidget(self.buttonOk)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout2)
        self.buttonOk.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        self.buttonCancel.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def handleLogin(self):
        password = self.textEdit.text()
        process = subprocess.Popen("sudo synaptic", 'w').write(password)
        #out = process.stdout.read(1)
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(process)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
            print "error code", error.returncode, error.output



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = PasswordDialog()

    if login.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your args to `subprocess.Popen` should be a list, try `['sudo', 'synaptic']`

Comment: check documentation for `Popen` - maybe other argument is assigned to `bufsize`

Comment: see [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen): second argument `w` is assigned to `bufsize` so you have two `bufsize`

Comment: The 'w' argument is passed to the `buffsize` parameter.

Comment: wouldn't `os.system('gksudo synaptic')` do the job?

Comment: or, if you prefer, `subprocess.Popen(['gksudo', 'synaptic'])`.

Comment: @xzoert os.system is deprecated. use  subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ought to use `communicate` to send the password to the `sudo` command.

Try this:

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "synaptic"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1) as process:
    process.communicate(password)
    process.wait()
```

The value of `process` should be a bytes string…

Comment: Thanks, might you know how to catch an output if the wrong password has been entered?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi ask a new question

Comment: I added `shell=True` it fixed some issues but them I'm getting error `with subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "synaptic"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True) as process:
AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi why don't you just read the documentation for `Popen`?

Comment: You're right, I've been treating Popen like it's the same as os.popen. I'll try the docs

Comment: Are you on Python 2? Don't use the `with` statement

Comment: I'm on python 2.7

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE. I think you meant: the value of `password`.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the wrong arguments to `Popen`.  The docs are here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

or even easier... just use the `call` function provided by the `subprocess` module:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'synaptic'])
```

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to send password to sudo from self.textEdit.text()?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi that's not the question you asked. you asked about how to call `sudo synaptic`.  I provided the answer.  That's sorta how it works here.  If you have a followup question about interacting with a spawned subprocess, then ask a new question.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg. To be fair to the OP, the code in the question includes an attempt to write a password to the process (although of course the syntax is all wrong, because they didn't read the popen docs).